# Почему не двигается персонаж в pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()

class Person:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.player = pygame.image.load('person.png')
        self.x = 400
        self.y = 300
        self.screen = screen
        self.speed = 5

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.player, (self.x, self.y))

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= self.speed

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = [600,900]
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(self.size)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
        self.person = Person(self.screen)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.person.move()

            self.screen.fill((255,255,255))
            self.person.draw()
            pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `pygame.K_DOWN` нужно написать `pygame.KEYDOWN`.